# Unable to load your default controller

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a Codeigniter Project where i add this to my routes.php File

**Routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site/landing";
$route['404_override'] = 'site/landing/page_not_found';
```

My directory structure is as

controllers --- site -- landing.php

**Landing.php**

```
class Landing extends MY_Controller {
   public function index(){
      # Some Code Here
   }

   public function page_not_found(){
      #load 404 page Here.. 
   }

}
```

**My_Controlelr.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  #Some COde Here.. 
}
```

Now when i go to some non existing URL like mydomain.com/ajsdhajksbcasbkjakjghdakjsdh

I get this error

> Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is
>   valid.

Comment: And `/site/landing/page_not_found` works?

Comment: No I get error instead of being redirected to page_not_found function.

Comment: Does any other URL work?

Comment: yes, default controoler works.. this problem occurs only when redirecting to 404 page

Comment: Can you please add another method to the Landing controller and test it. If it fails, then post your .htaccess as well.

Comment: @BaDDeveloper,Is this working? mydomain.com/index.php/ajsdhajksbcasbkjakjghdakjsdh